# Java/android setadapter - how unsort?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I know only 1 method to fill ListView

```
my_listviev.setAdapter(
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, some_list)
);
```

So I use some_list - list of definitions do not have a order.
How can i unsort listviev?
Specifically I would like to reverse the order (from Z to A).

Answer (score 1):

Use a Comparator for this:

```
public void sorterZA(ArrayList<String> listToSort) {

    Collections.sort(listToSort, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) * (-1);
        }
    });
}
```

Call this method first:

```
sorterZA(some_list);
```

Then, go ahead and set the adapter:

```
my_listviev.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, some_list));
```